# How do you copy text with hyperlinks (text is not the link, the link is embedded (href style)), with the links into org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I am copying text from a browser (from an email) which has hyperlinks such as [link text](https://google.com) - but the links do not get hyperlinked as in the email. I just see 'link text' when I paste to my org file. How do I achieve this?

I'm on doom emacs

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking at the email in emacs itself (using e.g. gnus or mu4 or one of the other email programs in emacs) and you had set up the [suggested global keybindings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) in Org mode, you could visit the link in emacs (e.g. using `eww`), then `C-c l` to remember it and then `C-c C-l` in the Org mode file to insert it (with the choice to give it a label as well).

You can set up `org-protocol` in a browser (see e.g. the [description in the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Protocols.html#Protocols) and some [setup instructions here](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-protocol-capture-html#org-protocol-instructions) - N.B. I have not tried them, so I don't know how well they work: YMMV), so that you could save links and arbitrary text, but that does take some fiddling to set it up, different browsers require different setup and IME it often breaks. OTOH, I haven't tried it in some years and so things might have improved since then.

But you can always do it manually: copy the link in your browser (e.g. bring up the context menu by right-clicking on the link and select "Copy Link" in Firefox), then paste it into your emacs and surround it with `[[...]]`, e.g. `[[https:///www.duckduckgo.com]]` - in Org mode, everything is just text after all - Org mode makes it *look* pretty (and does some other pretty amazing things as well) but you can always just type it in. You can prettify it a bit, by giving it a description: `[[https:///www.duckduckgo.com][Search]]`. You can even *type* the link by hand if you want as I did here, so this method, although somewhat tedious, is completely general.

Comment: ugh this is hard. Thank you for the answer. I wonder why this is not automatically supported. calls for a plugin I think.