# Importing text with hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlinks

I have a file in (say) odt format that contains hyperlinks, like [this](https://orgmode.org/), and I want to edit the content of this file using emacs-org. I can't just copy paste the content from *odt to *org, the links don't persist. What, then?

PS: there is [a post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68750/how-do-you-copy-text-with-hyperlinks-text-is-not-the-link-the-link-is-embedded) whose title seems to match my question, but the answer does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert the document from odt to org, and then I'd edit the newly created org document.

```bash
pandoc -r odt -w org example.odt > example.org
emacs example.org       # or
emacsclient example.org # if you have server-mode setup
```